# Rake aborted Uploading images using faker for ruby project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, faker

I am following a Ruby on Rails guide and ran into a problem generating fake content using the gem "Faker". I installed faker and followed the instructions to populate users and photos into my project.  I created this file in lib/tasks/populate.rake

lib/tasks/populate.rake

```
namespace :db do
  desc "Fill database with sample data"
  task populate: :environment do
    10.times do |n|
      puts "[DEBUG] creating user #{n+1} of 10"
      name = Faker::Name.name
      email =  "user-#{n+1}@example.com" 
      password = "password"
      User.create!( name: name,
                    email: email,
                    password: password,
                    password_confirmation: password)
    end

    User.all.each do |user|
      puts "[DEBUG] uploading images for user #{user.id} of #{User.last.id}"
      10.times do |n|
        image = File.open(Dir.glob(File.join(Rails.root, 'sampleimages', '*')).sample)
        description = %w(cool awesome crazy wow adorbs incredible).sample
        user.pins.create!(image: image, description: description)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now all I am supposed to do is put "rake db:populate" in my terminal (and in the right folder). When I do this I get:

```
rake db:populate
[DEBUG] creating user 1 of 10
[DEBUG] creating user 2 of 10
[DEBUG] creating user 3 of 10
[DEBUG] creating user 4 of 10
[DEBUG] creating user 5 of 10
[DEBUG] creating user 6 of 10
[DEBUG] creating user 7 of 10
[DEBUG] creating user 8 of 10
[DEBUG] creating user 9 of 10
[DEBUG] creating user 10 of 10
[DEBUG] uploading images for user 15 of 25
rake aborted!
can't convert nil into String
/Users/ScottDAlessandro/code/omrails/lib/tasks/populate.rake:18:in `initialize'
/Users/ScottDAlessandro/code/omrails/lib/tasks/populate.rake:18:in `open'
/Users/ScottDAlessandro/code/omrails/lib/tasks/populate.rake:18:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/ScottDAlessandro/code/omrails/lib/tasks/populate.rake:17:in `times'
/Users/ScottDAlessandro/code/omrails/lib/tasks/populate.rake:17:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/ScottDAlessandro/code/omrails/lib/tasks/populate.rake:15:in `each'
/Users/ScottDAlessandro/code/omrails/lib/tasks/populate.rake:15:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
Tasks: TOP => db:populate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

My big concern here is

"rake aborted!
can't convert nil into String"

It appears it created users but did not upload any pictures.

Question:

a) Why is rake being aborted?

b) How can I delete the users I created? The only way I know is" User.all" then User.delete(put a number here)...Are there more efficient ways of doing this?

Help would be greatly appreciated :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<rails_root>/sampleimages` directory is empty. `Dir.glob(...)` is returning an empty array and when you call `sample` it's returning `nil`. When you call `File.open(nil)` you get the exception and rake aborts.

If you want to delete all rows in the users table you can do `User.destroy_all`.