# Faker: Don't know how to build task 'enviroment'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this sample_data.rake file:

```
namespace :db do
desc "Fill Patients with sample data"
task populate: enviroment do
  Patient.create!(name: ["Example", "User"],
                  email: "example@gmail.com"
                  password: "foobar"
                  password_confirmation: "foobar"
                  age: "26"
                  doctor_id: "3"
                  dao: "true"
                  active: "true")
  350.times do |n|
    name=Faker::Name.name
    email = "example-#{n+1}@gmail.com"
    password = "password"
    age = (25...45).sample
    doctor_id = [2,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22].sample
    dao = ["true", "false"].sample
    active = "true"
    Patient.create!(name: name,                     
                email: email,                   
                password: password,             
                password_confirmation: password,
                age: age,                       
                doctor_id: doctor_id            
                dao: dao,                       
                active: active)  
    end
  end
end
```

It is placed on lib/tasks, and when i run rake db:populate I'm getting the next error.

```
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'enviroment'
/home/marcpursals/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@migtrace/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/home/marcpursals/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@migtrace/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:populate
```

I double checked this other posts: ([How to build task 'db:populate'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334520/dont-know-how-to-build-task-dbpopulate) , [Faker "Don't Know How to Build Task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904583/faker-dont-know-how-to-build-task) , [Rake aborted Uploading images using faker for ruby project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16994854/rake-aborted-uploading-images-using-faker-for-ruby-project..).) and they didn't help.

Does anyone solved a issue like this?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: It's a typo. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196985/232821

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`enviroment` should be `:environment`, as a correctly spelled Symbol.

```
task populate: :environment do
  # ...
```

Comment: OMG!!!! Sorry!! Thank for help... I'm embarassed...

Answer (score 1):

You spelt `enviroment` wrongly! It should be `environment`.

Comment: Hilarious. I did the same. Thanks for pointing it out.